# Checking conditions and assigning values by row in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has one row per subject, and there is a variable for which I want to reassign values based on a condition. For example, if the value of the variable is 6, I want to change the value to the mean of the other variables in the dataset.

```
Subject V1 V2 V3 V4
123     2  2  2  3
234     1  5  4  4
345     1  4  3  6
```

In the above dataset, for each patient, I want to reassign all 6's for V4 with the mean of that patient's V1, V2, V3. Thus, for subject 345, V4 would take on the new value `8/3 or ((1+4+3)/3)`. I was thinking of using an `ifelse` statement, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to replace for value 6 only in `V4` or all the columns?

Comment: Only for `V4`. I'm looking into the solutions posted right now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

data <- tibble(
  Subject = c("123", "234", "345"),
  V1 = c(2, 1, 1),
  V2 = c(2, 5, 4),
  V3 = c(2, 4, 3),
  V4 = c(3, 4, 6)
)
```

You could do this using base-R:

```
data$V4 <- ifelse(data$V4 == 6,(data$V1 + data$V2 + data$V3)/3, data$V4)
```

Or using a dplyr chain:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(V4 = ifelse(V4 == 6,(V1 + V2 + V3)/3, V4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the `V4` value to `NA` and replace them with `rowMeans`.

```
df$V4[df$V4 == 6] <- NA
df$V4 <- ifelse(is.na(df$V4), rowMeans(df[-1], na.rm = TRUE), df$V4)
df

#  Subject V1 V2 V3   V4
#1     123  2  2  2 3.00
#2     234  1  5  4 4.00
#3     345  1  4  3 2.67
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the below formula.

```
d[,4]<-ifelse(d[,4]==6,(d[,1]+d[,2]+d[,3])/3,d[,4])

d[,4]<-ifelse(d[,4]==6,rowMeans(d[,1:3]),d[,4])
```